# Permission denied on file deletion and previously copied in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Facing one issue....

Basically, I have a bouton on Word to launch a macro treatment. This treatment saves the open file, copies the open file from C:/ to Z:/, writes an XML file in Z:/, launches another treatment that will read both files in Z:/ and then, clears the files in Z:/.

C:/ is my local computer, Z:/ is a shared drive...

I managed to copy the file from C:/ to Z:/ with :

```
fsoObject.CopyFile ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.name, "Z:\" & ActiveDocument.name, True
```

Treatment goes well, but I'm completely unable to delete the file in Z:\ with this :

```
fsoObject.DeleteFile "Z:\*", True
```

I always get "Permission Denied"... Cannot delete it manually as well, except if I close ENTIRELY Word (and not only the file that was copied)...

Is there a way to avoid the file locking by Word ?

Thx !

Comment: You want delete all file in Z disc?

Comment: Yeap, Z:\ is a shared drive...

Comment: That will clear all files on Z? surly you just want to remove the file you have open? I dont think you will be able to delete the file until word is closed or resaved. If your doing this to move onto a next file save the open file as the new name and then delete old file

Comment: Well, actually, it's all a folder content I need to delete, but it should work the same... 

Basically, I have a bouton on Word to launch a treatment. This treatment saves the open file, copies the open file from C:/ to Z:/, launch another treatment that will read Z:/ and then, clear the file in Z:/. This macro writes a file in Z:/ as well, and I don't have any problem to delete it manually...

Comment: Please note that if I continue to modify the open document, Word will modify the doc on C:/ and not Z:/. So I really have the C:/ file opened.

Comment: Could you create a new instance of `Word.Application` to carry out the treatment of the file on Z, instead of using the current instance, and then close it programmatically? Also, are you closing the Z file programmatically? Perhaps post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vba command to close the file after you have performed your operations.  Then apply the delete command.

Comment: I don't want to close the file ! When I launch the treatment, I copy and I still have opened the file in C:/... Z:/ file is not opened !

Comment: well why not close out of word entirely through vba?  sorry- i'm not sure i understand the exact states of word being open/closed for the specific files

Comment: Because I need the launch the macro VBA on a special button on Word... I cannot close Word...